# Dimension of Cartesian products

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, dimension-theory

Is there a notion of dimension such that for all Borel sets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ we have
$$ \dim(A\times B)=\dim(A)+\dim(B)?$$ For topological, Minkowski, packing and Hausdorff dimension this is not true. If the answer is no (which I suppose) I like to understand which problems appear, if we try to give such a defintion of dimension.

Comment: What is the counterexample for the topological dimension? I'm familiar with some examples giving a strict inequality, but not as (Borel) subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$!

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti There are compact examples and any compact k-dimensional space admits an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{2\cdot k+1}$.

Comment: Could you list the properties that you want from dimension? (Otherwise, $\dim X\equiv 0$ is a solution.)

Comment: @Anton: Of course the dimension of a k-dim. manifold of cw-compex should be $k$. In addition I would like to have countable stability $\dim\cup A_{i}=\sup\dim A_{i}$ for Borel sets and the product law above.

Comment: Why not define the dimension of $A$ as a maximal number $k$ such that an orthogonal projection of $A$ to a $k$-dimensional plane contains a set of the second Baire category?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin $X=(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)$ and $X^2$ are homeomorphic, but the former is $G_\delta$ in the line and the latter in the plane, so your notion is not invariant under homeomorphisms

Comment: (which is not a property required by the asker, but I still think it's worth pointing out)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti right, if you assume that dimension is topological invariant, then you are in trouble, but we do not assume it.